# Create new in a Flask-admin foreign key field like Django-Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Let's say we have models A and B and the relation 1 - N therefore model B has an foreign key field named 'a'. Then I write a model view with this configuration:

```
class BAdmin(ModelView):
    ...
    form_rules = ('a',)
```

Having this configured I see that a select list is generated with all the entries of entity A but I would be a handful to have a link to create view for entity A next to the list pretty much like Django admin's default behavior.

[image: Django admin select]